# Add queries using a loop in neo4jclient c#

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I need to add a list of relationships to a node and in order to avoid matching that node every time I would like to do something like:

```
var query = client
.Cypher
.Match("(e:Element {...})");

foreach (var param in elem.parameters)
{
    query.Merge("(e)-[:HAS_PARAM]->(:Param {...})");
}
query.ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

That of course doesn't work, any other way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fluent interface, so every method returns a new query object.

In your `for` loop, you need to do `query = query.Merge(...)` to append the clause and use that as the basis for a growing query.